# Using Charindex to get data left of a character

Tags: sql, string, sybase, advantage-database-server

I have a field called subjects  and the data looks like this:

```
ALJ Diane Davis - WCF
```

I want my end result to be:

```
ALJ Diane Davis
```

I am trying to get all the data to left of the "-"
I am using Advantage SQL which I am new too.

The example below using the `RIGHT` function gets me everything to the right which works if i wanted that, but i dont always know the exact number of characters for the way that i am wanting my data to end up like.

Thanks in advance

```
left(appts.subject,charindex('-',appts.subject)

left(appts.subject,char('-',appts.subject)-1)

right(rtrim(appts.subject),6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
left(appts.subject, charindex('-', appts.subject) - 1)
```

If this fails because not all subjects have a `-`, then:

```
left(appts.subject, charindex('-', appts.subject + '-') - 1)
```

The above works in Sybase.  In Advantage SQL, I think you need `location`:

```
left(appts.subject, locate('-', appts.subject) - 1)
```

Comment: Im getting Scalar Function not found CHARINDEX.  I dont think advantage SQL using charindex function.

Comment: @BrianK . . . Your question is tagged Sybase, and `charindex()` is a Sybase function.

Comment: I am new to Advantage SQL, but not sql itself.  My understanding is that Sybase and advantage SQL are one in the same? is that not correct?

Comment: @BrianK . . . It is related to Sybase, but apparently they did not make the string functions backward compatible.

Comment: any idea if there is a similar function in Advantage SQL for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @BrianK . . . I've answered that.  It is called `locate()`.

Comment: This worked thank you.  left(appts.subject, locate('-', appts.subject) - 1)

Comment: so what happens when a record doesnt have a '-' in it?  I get an error about Invalid argument to scalar function  Left Length must be greater than 0.

Comment: @BrianK . . . The second query specifically addresses that point.  Just append a `'-'` in the string passed to `locate()`.

Comment: Yes but charindex doesnt work with Adv sql.  do i replace charindex with locate

Comment: @BrianK . . . Yes, it is the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you result. Locate is the function works in Adavantage-Sql. You can use this [link](https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.1/string_functions.htm)

> Function- LOCATE( str1, str2[, start] )
>
> Return integer location
> (1-based) of str1 in str2, with optional start starting point.
> If str1 is not found in str2, 0 is returned.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ALJ Diane Davis - WCF', 1, locate('-', 'ALJ Diane Davis - WCF') - 1)
```

Comment: I am using Advantage SQL and Charindex isn't a function.

Comment: We need to use locate function. Reflecting in the answer now.