# SQL Select everything to the left of a character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select everything to the left of a hyphen in a string, but some strings have 2 hyphens, in which case I need to select everything to the left of the second hyphen.

The strings are never the same length and some strings don't have hyphens at all.

Example data:

1. Manager-News Delivery
2. Co-Host-Television

Expected results:

1. Manager
2. Co-Host

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Hello. This looks like a list of requirements, not a programming question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Charindex to get data left of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633285/using-charindex-to-get-data-left-of-a-character)

Answer (score 2):

How about just removing everything from the last hyphen onward?

You can do that with `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(str, len(str) - charindex('-', reverse(str)) + 1, len(str), '')
from (values ('Co-Host-Television'), ('Manager-News Delivery')) v(str);
```

Or better yet, with `left()`:

```
select left(str, len(str) - charindex('-', reverse(str)) )
from (values ('Co-Host-Television'), ('Manager-News Delivery')) v(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL isn't really meant for string manipulation, you should do that type of work in another language (on the client side? maybe).
But, it you really, really want to, and the data is small and not something you'll need to do a lot, you can use the following code:

```
select rtrim(reverse(substring(reverse('Manager-News Delivery'),
       charindex('-',reverse('Manager-News Delivery'))+1,99)))
select rtrim(reverse(substring(reverse('Co-Host-Television'),
       charindex('-',reverse('Co-Host-Television'))+1,99)))
```